# How can I access my Service class from my ViewModel class?

Tags: android, service, viewmodel, android-livedata, foreground

I was recently learning about ViewModel and LiveData to build a countdown timer application project.

The thing is, I want my timer to run even when I close the app. So, I'm thinking of implementing my CountdownTimer in my Service class.

But I don't understand how to access this service class from my ViewModel class? Should I create my MutableLiveData within this service class and an observer in the activity?

Comment: Do you know how to access a service class everywhere else?

Comment: Not really. Earlier, when I was implementing a countdown timer in a service, I was using Toasts to show the time.

Comment: Will try to look at one of my examples with foreground service and adapt it to using viewmodel. It is an interesting use case.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what I'm really doing. I'm still quite new at this and I wanted to build a Countdown Timer project that can run even when the app is removed from the recent apps list.

I read that Services were one of the best ways to achieve this. However, I didn't know how to fetch data from the services class. That's where LiveData and ViewModel come in and I started learning those for the project.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering, how would you typically accomplish this task? Let's say, you were to build a similar project using services, how would you accomplish this without using the Architecture Components?

Comment: I will try to update one of my simple projects to use architecture components and services. I will update you when I am finished.